# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/GoogleInteractiveMediaAds.framework/GoogleInteractiveMediaAds Error in Custom Framework integration

Tags: ios, frameworks, dyld

I am creating a custom swift Framework inside this framework I am integrating **GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK** via adding **linked framework and libraries**. I am adding a custom framework to my project it creates Library not loaded error.

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/GoogleInteractiveMediaAds.framework/GoogleInteractiveMediaAds

Please suggest me how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

[The IMA iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/ios/client-side/download) is delivered now as `.xcframework`, not `.framework`. Just use the latest version.